# How do I get my app added to the OneLogin App Catalog?

Tags: saml, onelogin

I created a OneLogin dev account and have done the work to integrate my site (a dashboard for [Signal Sciences](https://www.signalsciences.com), a security company) with OneLogin via SAML.  I'd now like to add my site to the official OneLogin App Catalog.  Does anyone have any pointers on getting that done?

I've been here:

https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/app-catalog

and filled out the form, but got no confirmation and no response and have no idea how long I might need to wait for a response (if any).

I'd love any advice from someone who's been through this process.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your patience and for checking in. We did indeed receive your connector request--I believe the creation process is underway. Please let me know if you have not heard from a support rep as of yet.

When you initially submitted the request form, you should have received a confirmation email---but that did not happen. I apologize. We are investigating and will fix that issue.

Comment: Any idea how long the whole process usually takes? I had someone get back to me on June 14 asking for more info, I provided it on June 17, and now back to radio silence.

Comment: Hi Ross - thank you for asking. Depending on the volume of requests, the whole process takes 2-3 weeks. I'll add this info to the dev site to give people more of a heads up about what to expect.

Comment: Just for posterity, in my case the whole process took 6-7 weeks.